# Cannot Resolve Symbol Exception When Passing Runtime Type

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.0

I have a JSON deserializer (shown below) which works perfectly fine when I call it with a known type.

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(this object obj)
{
    var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    return (obj != null) ?
        javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>(obj.ToString()) :
        default(T);
}
```

So this call will work:

```
var newExampleTypeX = exampleJsonString.Deserialize<ExampleTypeX>();
```

However, what I'm trying to do is pass in a type which is set at runtime and use it in place of the "ExampleTypeX". When I do I get the following compilation error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'someType'
```

So the declaration of someType looks like so (this is a simplified version):

```
var someType = typeof(ExampleTypeX);
var newExampleTypeX = message.Deserialize<someType>();
```

Should I be altering my Deserialize extension method somehow, or altering how I pass in the runtime type? If so then how do I achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type used with generics has to be know compile-time. That's why you can't do that:

```
var someType = typeof(ExampleTypeX);
var newExampleTypeX = message.Deserialize<someType>();
```

It's not connected with JavaScriptSerializer - that's how generics work.

If you really need to, you can use reflection to bypass that, but I don't think you should.

You can read more about using reflection with generic types and extension method in that two questions:

[Generics in C#, using type of a variable as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107845/generics-in-c-using-type-of-a-variable-as-parameter)

[Reflection to Identify Extension Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299515/reflection-to-identify-extension-methods)

Comment: Thanks @MarcinJuraszek - if you have some code which illustrates how to achieve the above with reflection it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the end I found the solution through the Json.NET framework. It provides a lot more functionality than the .NET JavaScriptSerializer. Instead of having my own extension method I simply used the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, someType)