# How to call a method from of a property using Reflection

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, reflection, collections

I'm using nhibernate in a application and I have a mapped model with some relations. Theses relations are mapping with `List<T>` and I need to pass a entity to a method and call the `Any()` method to check if there are registers on each relation.

I try to do it but when I call `GetValue()` method from a PropertyInfo the NHibernate will load everything, but I need just to call `Any()` method to improve the performance and nhibernate will query a simple query just to check. I try this:

```
var type = entity.GetType();
foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties().Where(p => typeof (IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)))
{
   // it works, but load everything just to check if there are something...
   var collection = propertyInfo.GetValue(entity) as IEnumerable<dynamic>;

   if (collection != null)
      bool has = collection.Any();

}
```

I would like to call IEnumerable.Any() here, but how can I do this with reflection without GetValue?!

Comment: Fix your title; it doesn't match your question.

Comment: Have you defined your NHibernate property/collection to be lazy loading?

Comment: @Chris Sinclair, Yes, It is lazy loading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Enumerable.Any()` on a collection will cause initialization because the implementation reads to see if there are elements.

In contrast, if you map your collection with `lazy="extra"` you can check for `Count == 0` (it's an `ICollection<T>` method, you can call it easily if you use `dynamic`.

Alternatively, you can install [NHibernate.CollectionQuery](https://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.CollectionQuery/), map your collections using the queryable collection types, and call `collection.AsQueryable().Any()`.

Comment: Hi Diego, but how could I do it using reflection without calling `.GetValue` method from propertyInfo object? When I call GetValue, nhibernate will execute the complete query of my relation entity... :(

Comment: GetValue does NOT initialize the collection. You might be seeing that in the debugger, but it's the watches that are forcing it.

Answer (score 1):

`Any` is an extension method, so if you want to find it, check this post:
[Reflection to Identify Extension Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299515/reflection-to-identify-extension-methods)

But Entity will still load the entire list, since the `Any` method needs the whole list to apply a search pattern (even if it is empty).

Comment: Hi @ppetrov, you're right, I know the `Any()` method will hit a query just to check instead loading everything .. I also can call `Count()` method, but i will hit a `select count(*)...` on database, I preffer `select top 1 ...` and Any method hits it! I will check your link, thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure the `Any` method will generate a `select top 1` since it operates on a `IEnumerable`, so on an already loaded list. Does Entity Framework overloads this method so that it generates the `select top 1` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the IQueryable `Any()` extension method with the IEnumerable `Any()` extension method.

If you call `Any()` in a NHibernate Linq query (started by `session.Query<EntityType>()`) NHibernate sees that you only want to know if there is one element. It can do this because in that case you are using the extension method of `IQueryable` and are creating an expression tree instead of executing the code inside the extension method.

But if you call `Any()` on an persistent collection inside an entity this will just execute the code of the extension method. NHibernate sees this like any other access to the collection and loads the whole collection.

Comment: Hi @cremor, but how could I call this method genericly?!