# How to use C# extension methods with SmartFormat reflection syntax?

Tags: c#, reflection, extension-methods, smartformat.net

Is it possible to make the following example work with SmartFormat.NET?

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string,string> ps = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    ps["Name"] = "Niels";

    Smart.Format("{Name.Foo} is my name", ps).Dump();   
}


public static class Extensions
{

    public static string Foo(this string bar)
    {
        return bar.ToUpper();
    }

}
```

This will return " is my name" in LinqPad. I want it to return "NIELS is my name". I'm using ToUpper only as a simple example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

It is currently **not possible to call extension methods** inside `SmartFormat` formatting braces.

To provide such a feature, `SmartFormat` would have to look for an extension method of `string` in all the assemblies of your project, as described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299526/4325095).

### Example review

- **Inside the formatting string**

As specified in the [project documentation](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat.NET/wiki/Using-SmartFormat), you can use the **`ToUpper()` method directly inside the format braces**, like this (as the method does not take any parameter):

```
Smart.Format("{Name.ToUpper} is my name", ps).Dump();
```

Maybe the `SmartFormat` developers should introduce *Upper/Lowercase Format Specifiers* in the future, as many people are looking for such things. Nevertheless, it would be quite a challenge for them as `ToUpper()` and `ToLower()` calls always seems to be faster than any other implementation or syntactic sugar.

- **Outside the formatting string**

Another way to do it would be to call the **extension method outside of your formatting string**, but then you lose the [Reflection Syntax](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat.NET/wiki/Reflection-Syntax) advantages...

```
Smart.Format("{0} is my name", ps["Name"].Foo()).Dump();
```

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. I'll solve my problem with class that has a overriden ToString().

Answer (score 0):

No it will return **is my name**, can't call extensions method in SmartFormart.NET

Comment: Use comment lines for suggetions

Comment: Depend what logic he want