# how to query with Dapper with a type variable

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, inheritance, dapper

this is my setup

first, the base classes

```
public class TableBase
{
}

public class TableRepositoryBase
{
    private BindingSource _bindingSourceOnForm;

    public TableRepositoryBase(BindingSource bindingSource, string connectionString)
    {
        BindingSourceOnForm = bindingSource;
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
        SetupParameters();
    }

    protected string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    protected Type TableType { get; set; }

    protected BindingSource BindingSourceOnForm
    {
        get { return _bindingSourceOnForm; }
        set { _bindingSourceOnForm = value;}

    protected string SQLSelect { get; set; }

    protected virtual void SetupParameters()
    { }

    public virtual void FetchAll()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            BindingSourceOnForm.DataSource = connection.Query<TableType>(SQLSelect).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

now my inherited classes

```
public class TableUser : TableBase
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserFirst { get; set; }
    public string UserLastname { get; set; }
}

public class TableRepositoryUser : TableRepositoryBase
{
    public TableRepositoryUser(BindingSource bindingSource, string connectionString) : base(bindingSource, connectionString)
    { }

    protected override void SetupParameters()
    {
        base.SetupParameters();

        TableType = typeof(TableUser);
        SQLSelect = "select UserID, UserFirst, UserLastname from tblUser";
    }
}
```

Now the problem
In the base class `TableRepositoryBase` the following line of code in the method `FetchAll()` will not compile:

```
BindingSourceOnForm.DataSource = connection.Query<TableType>(SQLSelect).ToList();
```

The error is

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TableType' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This will be because the `query<>` is looking for a type, and although `TableType` is declared as a type, it will probably see it as a variable here.

What I want to achieve is that the method `FetchAll` can be done entire by the baseclass.
But, I would like that the list that is put in `BindingSourceOnForm.DataSource` is not of type `DapperRow` but in this case of type `TableUser`.

I could override this method in `TableRepositoryUser` like this

```
public override void FetchAll()
{
    //base.FetchAll();
    
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        BindingSourceOnForm.DataSource = connection.Query<TableUser>(SQLSelect).ToList();
    }
}
```

That will work, now the list assigned to `BindingSourceOnForm.DataSource` if of type `TableUser`
But I would like to do this code in the base class, not in the inherited class.
How could I achieve this ?

**EDIT**
I am trying to adapt the answers from the link I got in the comments from @Flydog57 but with no success.
I have this so far

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(SqlConnection).GetMethod("Query");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(TableType);

BindingSourceOnForm.DataSource = generic.(SQLSelect).ToList();
```

I get a compile error `Identifier expected`
I guess this code makes no sense at all, but I dont understand how to use `MakeGenericMethod` to solve my problem, if it is even possible.

So some help here would be appreciated

**EDIT 2**

Since I can't find a solution, I am now using this inefficient method

```
public virtual void FetchAll()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        if (TableType == typeof(TableUser))
            BindingSourceOnForm.DataSource = connection.Query<TableUser>(SQLSelect).ToList();
        else if (TableType == typeof(TableTask))
            BindingSourceOnForm.DataSource = connection.Query<TableTask>(SQLSelect).ToList();
    }
}
```

Still hoping for a better way because this means I have to come back here and alter the code everytime a new repository class is inherited from RepositoryBase

Comment: `TableType` is a variable of type `System.Type`, not a type.  You can't directly call a generic function with a variable, only with a type.  You have to use Reflection to do this (`MakeGenericFunction`).  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you for this link. I am however having trouble in extracting an answer for my case from the answers in that question that would solve my problem. Maybe you could write a little sample on how to do that in a way I can use it in my situation ?

Comment: Dapper can query using `dynamic` variables.  Maybe this will help you.  At some point, however, I see a Factory method in your future, unless you can bind your forlm to a to a `List<dynamic>`.  For what it's worth, putting the conversion in the derived class is pretty much the whole point of runtime polymorphism.

Comment: See also https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-dapper-generic-repository/

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually you are right. I should override this method in the derived class and let polymorphism do its job. I guess I did some overthinking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming what you are trying to do is to translate this:

```
public virtual void FetchAll()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        BindingSourceOnForm.DataSource = connection.Query<TableType>(SQLSelect).ToList();
    }
}
```

into functioning code, that calls `connection.Query` using the type represented by `TableType` as the generic parameter to the `Query` function.

Rather than using your abstract code, I'm using the SQL Pubs database sample (I had it on my laptop) and an `Authors` class I threw together.  So the code I'm going to translate looks like this:

```
public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = @"Data Source=[MyLaptopName];Trusted_Connection=true";
public string SelectString { get; set; } = @"SELECT TOP (1000) [au_id], [au_lname], [au_fname],[phone],[address],[city],[state],[zip],[contract]FROM [pubs].[dbo].[authors]";
```

With an Authors class that looks like:

```
public class Authors
{
    public string au_id { get; set; }
    public string au_lname { get; set; }
    public string au_fname { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
    public string contract { get; set; }
}
```

I can read the contents of that table with this minimalist code:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    var result = conn.Query<Authors>(SelectString);
}
```

So, starting with [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method) as a guide, the first roadblock is how to get a reference to the `MethodInfo` that represents the call to Query.

That's an extension method on `SqlConnection` that is implemented as a static method on the `Dapper.SqlMapper` class.  It's generic and has a single type parameter.  The particular override we are going to call has seven parameters (there are 11 Query methods defined in `Dapper.SqlMapper` - we need to pick the right one).

I'm getting the method this (rather brute-force) way:

```
private MethodInfo GetDapperQueryMethod()
{
    var dapperMapperType = typeof(Dapper.SqlMapper);
    //get the first method named "Query" that has a single generic type parameter and seven regular parameters
    var queryMethods = dapperMapperType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(m => m.Name == "Query" && m.IsGenericMethod && m.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 && m.GetParameters().Length == 7);
    return queryMethods.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

You might want to look at this for other ways of doing this: [Reflection to Identify Extension Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299515/reflection-to-identify-extension-methods)

Once we have the `MethodInfo` that represents the correct override of `Query`, the rest is reasonably simple.  First, you need to fabricate the generic method, combining the generic method definition with the generic parameter type (`TableType` in your case, `Authors` in mine).  You create that MethodInfo using `MakeGenericMethod`.

You need to call that method - but as a simple static method (reflection mostly doesn't care about extension methods).  So, the first parameter is the connection.  The final parameters are the default values that each of the parameters have (after the connection and the query string).  So:

```
var method = GetDapperQueryMethod();
var authorsType = typeof(Authors);
var genericQuery = method.MakeGenericMethod(authorsType);
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    var result = genericQuery.Invoke(null, new object[] {conn, SelectString, null, null, true, null, null});
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention.  In the last bit of code I show, the static type of `result` is `object` (since that's what `Invoke` returns).  You can cast it to `IEnumerable(Author)` if you want.  You can't do that, though when you use your `TableType` variable.  The underlying type is a collection of that type, but because of the contravariance of `IEnumerable<T>` you may need to stand on your head to get this in a form you want.